# Secondary hard drive keeps unmounting (Linux)

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Ever since I moved to Fedora, I've been having issues with my secondary hard drive (sdc). I use it to store my games, but it keeps randomly unmounting, even when I'm not playing any games (even though, happens mostly when playing to games).

At first, I thought the issue was with fstab, probably some wrong entry or something. I also found out that Valve does not recommend mounting your other game drives on your home directory.

**What I've tried**

1. Formatting the drive
2. Changing the mount point from /home/user/Games to /run/media/user/Games
3. Removing the /etc/fstab entry for that drive altogether
4. Reinstalling Fedora

I really don't know what could be causing this. I want to believe that the drive is not failing, because I bought it in late 2021. This issue does not happen with my other internal and external drives, only with this one.

Fortunately, I took a screenshot of the logs, right when it got unmounted:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of9Yo.png)

**Edit**

This is the output of SMART:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.12-200.fc37.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5 (CMR)
Device Model:     ST1000DM010-2EP102
Serial Number:    ZN1HY181
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0c6bf9d54
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Feb 22 22:11:54 2023 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 105) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   063   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       183660535
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3449
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   075   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       8653888438
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       8389
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2737
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1724
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   098   071   000    Old_age   Always       -       4 4 246
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   069   054   040    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 29/32)
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3494
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   031   013   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (0 13 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   007   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       183660535
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12612
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7871h+40m+42.835s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       19772290294
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       34697736665

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

And the output of `sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc1`

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Games: recovering journal
Setting free inodes count to 61051822 (was 61051825)
Setting free blocks count to 232203314 (was 232204073)
Games: clean, 3154/61054976 files, 11986894/244190208 blocks
```

Comment: (1) In the log you posted there are problems with `sdc` and `sdd`. Which one is the disk in question? Is it `sdc` (like in your `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`)? (2) In what way is the disk powered?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The disk with problems is /dev/sdc. It is just an internal HDD, plugged in via Sata. But now that I think about it, I think that every time it gets unmounted, the drive is assigned the following letter (becomes /dev/sdd and so on)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but looking at the logs, I think this could well be one or both of 2 things -

1. The drive may be failing.  Have a look at S.M.A.R.T to see what the drive thinks of itself.  If you have smartmontools installed, you can get some information with a command like

   sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
2. It seems to me like the ext4 filesystem is corrupt.  Ideally do a bitcopy of the drive before trying to repair it as their is a risk of data loss.  I believe you can use something like the below to fix it (on the unmounted drive)

   sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc1

Comment: Agreed on the drive failure. It'd be interesting to know if it's an HDD or SSD (or hybrid). It's a short duration (since 2021). Temperature may cause quick damages. Check this on SMART - 40/45°C is fine, above I would try to reduce it.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. SMART doesn't seem to throw any error, but when I played CS:GO again, it unmounted the drive again. I'm also experiencing a lot of stutters. I'm more confused now

Comment: Did you fsck the drive as well?